# Getting the address of a function

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm playing around with ASM, byte code and executable memory.

I'm using `echo -e "<asm instruction here>" | as -o /dev/null -64 -al -msyntax=att` to "compile" my code. Anyways, I noticed that `movq 2, %rax` will result in `0000 488B0425 02000000`, but both `call printk` and `call printf` will result in `0000 E8000000 00`, which I believe is because of the fact that `as` doesn't know anything about `printk` or `printf`.

My question is how can I get the address of those functions so I can use them in my byte code?

Comment: To produce code which can actually run, you need to use linker too. Just build time for static symbols (which are in know position in the output), and for dynamic libraries, both build time, and then again when you load the code (either automatically at program startup, or by loading a dynamic library with right function calls at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

The assembler does not know the values of external symbols. It writes a file with multiple sets of data in it. One set of data is the bytes to put into a program’s text section. Another set of data is information about external symbols used and what adjustments to make to the bytes in the text section when those external symbols are resolved. The file produced by the assembler does not contain any information about the values of symbols that come from external libraries.

The linker resolves external symbols. When producing a *statically linked* executable, it will fully resolve the external symbols. When producing *dynamically linked* executable, resolution of external symbols is completed during program execution.

After you statically link an executable, you can use a tool such as `nm` to see the values of symbols in it (if they have not been stripped). Then you could use those values in assembly. However, hardcoding those values into assembly will fail if the program is ever linked in a different way, that puts the routines at different locations.

If you dynamically link an executable, you would have to inspect the executing program to determine where its external symbols were placed. Again, you could in theory use those values in assembly, but this would be even more prone to failure than doing so with static linking, especially on systems that deliberately change the addresses used in executables to thwart malicious code.

Hard-coding symbol values into assembly is not the normal way of writing assembly language or other code and should not be done except for learning or special-purpose debugging or system inspection.

Comment: That explanation is great! Anyways, I still don't know how can I get the address of printk at runtime. How could I do it?

Comment: @alexandernst: The easiest way may be to run the program in a debugger, stop it at some place after `printk` has been loaded (possibly in `printk` itself) and tell the debugger to print/show you the value of `printk`.

Comment: @alexandernst In C, to get address of function at runtime, just have function name without parenthesis: `printf ("Addr of printk: %p\n", printk);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper tool to inspect your object files. Assuming any Unix, use

```
 nm -AP file.o
```

to see the addresses of all symbols (functions and variables). Since printf is likely in a library, run `nm` on that library for the same effect.

Comment: How portable would that be? I mean, would that limit the application to just my computer? Or just to all the computers using exactly that same library version?

Comment: It wouldn't be very portable. Modern systems use virtual memory and the code for any function could be at any address. A dynamic linker resolves the unresolved symbols when the program is loaded into memory. The `nm -AP` output shows these symbols with an `U` for *unresolved and to be resolved*.